# Stimual soft report

Tags: stimulsoft

on sending the data to the report this error is shown to me 
the businesses object is 5 column of strings named ReportData

public ActionResult GetReport()
        {
            List ItemExpiredReportViewModelList = new List();

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ItemExpiredReportViewModel ItemExpiredReportViewModela = new ItemExpiredReportViewModel();
            ItemExpiredReportViewModela.ItemName = "ItemName ".ToString();
            ItemExpiredReportViewModela.ItemCode = "ItemCode ".ToString();
            ItemExpiredReportViewModela.ItemUnit = "ItemUnit ".ToString();
            ItemExpiredReportViewModela.ExpireDate = "ExpireDate".ToString();
            ItemExpiredReportViewModela.Balance = "Balance ".ToString();
            ItemExpiredReportViewModelList.Add(ItemExpiredReportViewModela);
        }

        StiReport report = new StiReport();

        report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Admin/Reports/TestStimulsoft/Report.mrt"));
        report.RegBusinessObject("ReportData", ItemExpiredReportViewModelList);
        report.Compile();


        CheckReference(report);
        return StiMvcViewer.GetReportResult(report); 
    }
```

c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\s3iq5rsq.0.cs(950,13) : error CS0126: An object of a type convertible to 'string' is requiredc:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\s3iq5rsq.0.cs(955,13) : error CS0126: An object of a type convertible to 'string' is requiredc:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\s3iq5rsq.0.cs(960,13) : error CS0126: An object of a type convertible to 'string' is requiredc:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\s3iq5rsq.0.cs(965,13) : error CS0126: An object of a type convertible to 'string' is requiredc:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\s3iq5rsq.0.cs(970,13) : error CS0126: An object of a type convertible to 'string' is required

at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile(String path, Stream stream, StiOutputType outputType, Boolean autoCreate, Object standaloneReportType) in D:\Stimulsoft\Stimulsoft.Reports\Stimulsoft.Report\StiReport.Compile.cs:line 435
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile() in D:\Stimulsoft\Stimulsoft.Reports\Stimulsoft.Report\StiReport.Compile.cs:line 134
   at HMS.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.AddTransactionController.GetReport() in D:\HMS3\HMS.Web\Areas\Admin\Controllers\AddTransactionController.cs:line 405
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__11_0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.b__2()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I suppose that you forgot: a) include your code in post, b) describe your problem

Comment: Most likely in the data dictionary for some column specified a type, which can not be explicitly converted to "string".
Therefore, the compiler produces the error "An object of a type convertible to 'string' is required".

For a more accurate answer, we need to examine your report template and the code of your business object.